Can't configure google_sign_in without firebase
I install google_sign_in and create successfully my keytool sha key , i configure my google console acccount and create credentials (i enable also People API).
I pass my generate keytool file into android/app folder and put that code in build.grandle :
 signingConfigs{
        debug{
            keyAlias 'xxxxx'
            storePassword 'xxxxx'
            storeFile file('xxxxx.jks')
            keyPassword 'xxxxx'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug{
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

Also i put that on manifest :
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" />

When i run it it still gives me errors like this :
I/flutter (32747): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

What else i forgot ?
Here is my fluter code :
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: ['email'],
  clientId:"XXXXXXXXXXXX"
);

Future<void> google_LogIn(BuildContext context) async {
  try {
    print(1);
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    print(2);
    if (googleUser != null) {
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;
      print(3);
      print('Token : ${googleAuth.idToken!}');
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('${dotenv.env['baseUrl']}/auth_google'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'idToken': googleAuth.idToken!,
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(response.body);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
              content: Text('Sign in successful! Welcome ${user['name']}')),
        );
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to sign in with Google')),
        );
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('Error occurred during Google sign in: $error')),
    );
    print(error);
  }
}

And my node server :

const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');

    //Google Auth
    async auth_google(req, res) {
        try {
            const token = req.body.idToken;
            const payload = await logIn_Controller.verify(token);
            res.status(200).json(payload);
          } catch (error) {
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid token' });
          }
    },
    
    
    async verify(token) {
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
          idToken: token,
          audience: CLIENT_ID,
        });
        const payload = ticket.getPayload();
        return payload;
    },

When i try to print the token is null also .
Some times if i comment the scopes and clientId it says this :
I/flutter (18971): Null check operator used on a null value

So what is my problem ?
The node server is not even triggered so something wrong about auth ,specific in this command :
   final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;

Because the first one is returning some info data about the users .So im guessing that is something wrong in that specific command.
